# how to change window color on mac os

Tags: macos, operating-system, window, uicolor

mac os: 10.10
xcode:6.1

I got a "default cocoa program" by Xcode. and I want to change the window color...after researching, I did the following code in AppDelegate.m:

```
NSWindow *myWindow;
NSColor *semiTransparentBlue =
[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
[myWindow setBackgroundColor:semiTransparentBlue];
```

but window color not changed...

1: how to change the window color on mac os?
2: no NSWindow in "Default cocoa program" by Xcode, why will get a window?

thank your very much.

i tried some functions...but failed..following is the detail:

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  // Insert code here to initialize your application

  //compile success but the window's color is not changed.
  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];

  //or the following two got compiled error
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}

Answer (score 0):

in your app delegate juste type this :

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: in your AppDelegate find the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and add it here

Comment: only applicationDidFinishLaunching, Not found didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. should i write it by myself? thanks.

Comment: - (void)didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    
    self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    
}   //still error...

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.9];
    return YES;
}

Comment: still error....could you build it on you mac? i run the code on MAC OS 10.10, Xcode 6.1...failed..

Comment: i have test it now with xcode 6.1 and it work, did you find the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in your AppDelegate ??